# Plugin managers in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am going to write my own abstract factory, similar to the [`Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Log/LoggerAbstractServiceFactory.php). I noticed that this abstract factory [works with plugin managers](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Log/LoggerAbstractServiceFactory.php#L94-L120), but I am wondering exactly what the purpose of plugin managers is - both in general and in this particular example. The `Zend\Log` namespace includes multiple plugin managers such as `WriterPluginManager` and `ProcessorPluginManager`, while the `Zend\Log\Writer` namespace includes the `FormatterPluginManager` class. Basically I am confused as to what exactly these plugin managers do.

I know that there are several plugin managers for controller plugins, view helpers, etc., and I noticed that a plugin manager is a specialized service locator because the `Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager` class [extends](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php#L22) `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager`.

So my question is: what is the purpose of plugin managers, both in general, and in the concrete example of the `Zend\Log` namespace? I couldn't really find any documentation on this.

Comment: [this](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/zend-framework-2-getting-closer-with-pluginmanager/) was my start and I have never looked back!

Answer (score 2):

A plugin manager is a special service manager which returns a particular type of services. They define a `validatePlugin()` method which checks that the service is indeed of the correct type. From the examples you gave, `WriterPluginManager` returns log writers and `ProcessorPluginManager` unsurprisingly returns log processors.

You shouldn't need to worry too much about the specifics of this as long as your abstract factory returns classes implementing the correct interface.

Answer (score 0):

pluginManager created to manage controller plugin . controller plugin execute on all request for example if you want check authorization or log , best place is controller plugin or any task should do on all request .